# AWS Lambda event structure gets full request from API Gateway using Axios in React app

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I am implementing a polling mechanism for a react app using axios to post to an API that triggers a Lambda function from AWS.

The same Lambda function is triggered by the same API from an Android app and everything behaves as it should. Right now, the Lambda function only prints the `event` in the logs.

This event, from the Android app, looks like this in the logs:

```
{'hr': '[67, 67, 69, 70, 66, 67, 68, 72, 71, 72]'}
```

But when I post from the React App with axios I get this:

```
{'resource': '/qmed_data_feed', 'path': '/qmed_data_feed', 'httpMethod': 'OPTIONS', 'headers': {'accept': '/', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'accept-language': 'en,es-AR;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,es-PY;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6', 'access-control-request-headers': 'content-type', 'access-control-request-method': 'POST', 'Host': '2osztvec25.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'origin': 'http://localhost:3000', 'referer': 'http://localhost:3000/', 'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty', 'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors', 'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-5eb222b9-dee35fb587d5ed0083dc8600', 'X-Forwarded-For': '181.94.228.87', 'X-Forwarded-Port': '443', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https'}, 'multiValueHeaders': {'accept': ['/'], 'accept-encoding': ['gzip, deflate, br'], 'accept-language': ['en,es-AR;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,es-PY;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6'], 'access-control-request-headers': ['content-type'], 'access-control-request-method': ['POST'], 'Host': ['2osztvec25.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'], 'origin': ['http://localhost:3000'], 'referer': ['http://localhost:3000/'], 'sec-fetch-dest': ['empty'], 'sec-fetch-mode': ['cors'], 'sec-fetch-site': ['cross-site'], 'User-Agent': ['Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'], 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': ['Root=1-5eb222b9-dee35fb587d5ed0083dc8600'], 'X-Forwarded-For': ['181.94.228.87'], 'X-Forwarded-Port': ['443'], 'X-Forwarded-Proto': ['https']}, 'queryStringParameters': None, 'multiValueQueryStringParameters': None, 'pathParameters': None, 'stageVariables': None, 'requestContext': {'resourceId': 'x2sz4i', 'resourcePath': '/qmed_data_feed', 'httpMethod': 'OPTIONS', 'extendedRequestId': 'MFpdBFRViYcF60Q=', 'requestTime': '06/May/2020:02:36:41 +0000', 'path': '/default/qmed_data_feed', 'accountId': '262418700729', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 'stage': 'default', 'domainPrefix': '2osztvec25', 'requestTimeEpoch': 1588732601628, 'requestId': 'ef1a6730-3fb3-4262-8a64-8492c2c26eeb', 'identity': {'cognitoIdentityPoolId': None, 'accountId': None, 'cognitoIdentityId': None, 'caller': None, 'sourceIp': '181.94.228.87', 'principalOrgId': None, 'accessKey': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationType': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationProvider': None, 'userArn': None, 'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36', 'user': None}, 'domainName': '2osztvec25.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'apiId': '2osztvec25'}, 'body': None, 'isBase64Encoded': False}
```

and body key is empty: `'body': None,`

I tested the Api using api tester and it also worked fine.

This is my code to post with Axios:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const payload = {
  command: "get",
  user: "000"
}

export const useLambdaApi = () => {
  const [data1, updateData1] = useState([]);
  const api = 'https://2osztvec25.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/qmed_data_feed';
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try{
        let result = {};
        result = await axios.post(api, payload);
        console.log(result)
      } catch (error){
        console.log("ERROR",error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  },[]);
  return [data1, updateData1];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT

So, the response I get in the react app is this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<apiURL>' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know that might be a problem with the headers, but that is only because the Lambda function fails with a key error and doesn't return the headers. The problem is the request content sent by the React app

Comment: I've got this same issue... did you every figure it out?

Comment: Never found the problem... Some specs changed and we dropped the polling approach. Sorry.